# Page refresh returns a 404error with Polymer Firebase (can't find routed page)

Tags: javascript, firebase, routes, polymer, polymer-1.0

In my current project with Polymer & Firebase I am having the issue that on page refresh none of my routed pages gets found 404. 
I created a new project that produces the same error and hosted it with firebase.
I make use of google authentication and after a successful sign-up I load my application which is basically the Polymer stater-kit. I believe that the problem is the structure of my pages/project. Because my-app is just the gateway to my-site which holds the routing and the corresponding pages.
I added a image below to explain how my project is structured. I also added picture of the source in my console. ones when routed to the page and one when the page was reload.

**I would really appreciate if someone finds the time to look at this**

**Picture of my project structure**
[image: Project structure]

**Picture of my console**
[image]
[image]

**firebase.json file**

```
{
  "database": {
  "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
  "public": "public"
  }
}
```

**firebase.json file from my actual project with same problem**

```
{
  "database": {
  "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
  "public": "public",
  "rewrites": [
    {
    "source": "**/!{*.*}",
    "destination": "/index.html"
    }
    ]
  }
 }
```

**Code for my index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>polyfire</title>
  <link rel="import" href="my-app.html">
  <style media="screen">
   body {
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <my-app></my-app>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Code for my my-app.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="my-login.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-site.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">
 <template>
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

  <firebase-app
    auth-domain="firebaseapp.com"
    database-url="firebaseio.com"
    api-key="..."
    storage-bucket="gs://yole.appspot.com">
  </firebase-app>

  <firebase-auth user="{{user}}"></firebase-auth>

  <template is="dom-if" if="[[!user]]">
    <my-login></my-login>
  </template>

  <template is="dom-if" if="[[user]]">
    <my-site></my-site>
  </template>

</template>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-app',
    properties: {},
  });
</script>
```

**Code of my-login.html**

```
<dom-module id="my-login">
<template>
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

  <firebase-auth
    id="auth"
    user="{{user}}"
    status-known="{{statusKnown}}"
    provider="google"
    on-error="handleError"></firebase-auth>

  <paper-button class="logInOutBtn" raised on-tap="login" hidden$="[[user]]">Sign-up with Google</paper-button> 
  <paper-button class="logInOutBtn" raised on-tap="logout" hidden$="[[!user]]">Sign-out</paper-button>

</template>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-login',

    properties: {
      user: {
        type: Object,
      },
      statusKnown: {
        type: Object,
      }
    },
    login: function() {
      this.$.auth.signInWithPopup();
    },
    logout: function() {
      this.$.auth.signOut();
    },

  });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you're not rewriting your URLs at the server level. Thus, when you're moving from the homepage to other routes, it works, but if you wish to get to a specific page without going through the homepage, it fails, because the server doesn't know what route you're talking about.

If you use `firebase serve`, you can let the URL rewriting [happen like so](https://github.com/seanmavley/madewithfirebase.firebaseapp.com/blob/master/firebase.json) after specifying this in the `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "app",
      "rewrites": [{
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
    }]
  }
}
```

Depending on your configuration, you might have to change the values above. But the focus is the `rewrites` part.

**Another approach.**

If you're using something like Gulp to serve your site, you might wanna take a look at how to do URL rewriting at that level too. [See this for a complete](https://github.com/seanmavley/madewithfirebase.firebaseapp.com/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L57) picture, but in short:

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browser.init({
        server: 'app/',
        port: port,
        middleware: [historyApiFallback()] // See link above for details
    });
    .....
});
```

I don't know how you'll end up deploying your app, but the bottom line might be to rewrite the URLs.

Comment: thanks so much for that quick response.
I had the feeling that the problem is connected to that but not enough experience to know what exactly is going on there. I deploy my app with firebase deploy the link is in the question. I updated my question and included my firebase.json file.

Comment: @NiklasLang If you deploy with Firebase, then check my `firebase.json` file and see how the rewrites is done, and try with your configuration if it works.

Comment: Man you are a life saver super fast answer and on top of it it solved my problem on the test app and my actual app. Thanks